# How to change the location of details pane in Windows 8 file explorer (to left side)

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-explorer

I have been looking for a way to change the location of details pane in Windows 8 file explorer. All I've found is how to show it on bottom just like Windows 7. But I want to move it to the left side of the window, where usually navigation bar is located. Any ideas?

Comment: This won't be possible unless you replace the explorer shell with something else.

Comment: ask this the author of OldNewExplorer, so that he can implement it: http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/170375-oldnewexplorer-make-your-81-explorer-work-like-win78-one/

Comment: Thanks guys. I just posted the question in OldNewExplorer thread.